# How to disable Datomic logs?

Tags: logging, clojure, logback, datomic

I've configured my app's logback configuration and it turned out Datomic uses logback for it's logging and my console populated with Datomic's logs which I don't need.

How can I disable Datomic's logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer varies depending on which Datomic process you are talking about, and on where (other than the console) you want the logs to go.

Datomic uses logback on the transactors, but uses SLF4J for indirection on the peers, and [documents the configuration](http://docs.datomic.com/configuring-logging.html) for both.

Comment: Actually, want to disable Datomic Metrics Reporter.

Comment: Even I comment out most of the config in /bin/logback.xml it still shows Datomic Metrics(datomic.process-monitor) but very less.Also need to disable that one, any ideas?

Comment: If you're talking about datomic logs in your app that connects via the peer library (as opposed to logs on the transactor itself), I've found that this line in my app's logback.xml cuts down on the datomic noise considerably: `<logger name="datomic" level="WARN"/>`